# When to use Indexers instead of Fields

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone clarify with  some real examples when we have to use `Indexers` instead of `Fields` in C# classes?

```
public class GradeHolder
{
    private int[] counts = new int[100];

    public int this[int grade]
    {
        get { return this.counts[grade];}
        set { this.counts[grade] = value; }
    }
}

public class GradeHolder
{
    private int[] counts = new int[100];

    public void SetCount(int index, int grade)
    {
        counts[index] = grade;
    }

    public int GetCount(int index)
    {
        return counts[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: :read this http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never **have** to use indexers.

They are convenient when the data structure is one that is naturally indexed.

And the comparison with fields is very misleading - they are different things and can't really be directly compared (not in terms of when to use one over the other).

An indexer is simply a way to access certain elements of the type using some sort of index. Fields are what you use to hold the state of the type (including what you will be indexing *into*, if at all).

You can also use both in the same class:

```
public class GradeHolder
{
    private int[] counts = new int[100];

    public int[] Counts 
    { 
       get { return this.counts; }
       set { this.counts = value; }

    public int this[int grade]
    {
        get { return this.counts[grade];}
        set { this.counts[grade] = value; }
    }
}
```

The indexer will return a single item from the list, at the specified index.

I have replaced the `Get/Set` methods with a property, which is the more idiomatic C# (for simple properties).

---

Update:

Now that you have changed your `Get/Set` methods to something closer to what an indexer does, the answer to which of the two one would prefer is of course the indexer.

Why?

- Because you only have 1 parameter, not two.
- Because indexers are well understood by other programmers and are what people will expect ([principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)).
- Because it is more idiomatic.

Comment: Could you take a look at the question I just added some samples and say  if one approach is better than another one, please?

Comment: @Peretz - You are again, doing two different things. The indexer returns a single _count_ in the passed in index. The second class (with Get/Set methods) returns the complete collection and should probably be done with a property.

Comment: @Peretz - Changing the question after getting answers about the original code is not very nice and makes the answers given invalid - even though they were not so when given. Please, if you post "incorrect" code, at least consider changing things so current answers are still valid.

Answer (score 1):

When you want your class to behave like a collection (or more likely, encapsulating one), treating different values based on some kind of index. It's syntactic sugar, really.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: This answer is for a previous version of the question.

In your second implementation, a caller can (must) entirely replace the counts field, including setting it to null or changing it's size.

The first implementation protects the counts field, giving access only to each element. It also allows the implementation to change from int[] to anything else later.